# What map editors are available to me for Source engine games?

Tags: source-engine

I was looking to improve some TF2 maps made by some of my friends.  I have some average-ish modelling experience.

What map editors are available to me for Source engine games, and where can I get them?

I've been looking all over for Hammer 4.1, but I can't seem to find this anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Valve Developer Community](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Main_Page), you can find a lot of ressources regarding the Source SDK, level design and much more.
I your case I would look at:

- [Installing the Source SDK](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Downloading_and_Installing_the_Source_SDK)
- [Level Design FAQ](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Category:Level_Design_FAQ)